# Is there a Way to change a href value from a link with CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress theme which does not grant access to .html files, its loads the html which I need to style like this:

```
<!--Header Start-->

<?php get_template_part( 'templates/headers/xv', 'nav' ); ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'templates/headers/search', 'bar' ); ?>
```

I need to make changes in the header, there is a link which simpy has to be changed

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="http://THISMUSTBECHNAGED.eu/">
<img src="Image.png" >
</a>
```

I have checked all possibilites which the template itself offers and didnt found a possibility to change the link destination, also the Text Editor in Wordpress grants access to all the .php files, but none of them is working with the navbar, it loads it from get_template_part as I show in the first code sample.

Thats what I tried witch JS, but didnt worked:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementByClassName("navbar-brand").href="NEWLINK";
});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navbar-brand").attr("href", "NEWLINK")
});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-brand");
    x[0].href = "NEWLINK";
});
```

Is there a way to select this href with css und change the link this way?

Thats the theme: http://xvelopers.com/wp/themes/voltov/

The Full header.php:

```
<?php?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]--   >
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<?php global $xv_data; //fetch options stored in $xv_data ?>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" />
<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php if(!empty($xv_data['fav_icon']

['url'])){ echo esc_url($xv_data['fav_icon']['url']);}else{ echo 

esc_url(get_template_directory_uri() .  '/assets/img/favicon.png'); }?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?> data-spy="scroll" data-target=".pages-wrapper">
<div class="wrapAllContent">
<!--Header Start-->

<?php get_template_part( 'templates/headers/xv', 'nav' ); ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'templates/headers/search', 'bar' ); ?>
```

**EDIT:**

Thats the .php which is used to create the navbar element and the homelink is created via boolean = true, setting it to false doesnt make my JS work. I have no clue how to customize this:

```
    <?php

/**

 * xvelopers's Theme Core Functions 

 *

 * Eventually, some of the functionality here could be replaced by core features

 *

 * @package voltov

 */



/**

 * Get our wp_nav_menu() fallback, wp_page_menu(), to show a home link.

 *

 * @param array $args Configuration arguments.

 * @return array

 */

function voltov_page_menu_args( $args ) {

    $args['show_home'] = true;

    return $args;

}

add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'voltov_page_menu_args' );







/**

 * Adds custom classes to the array of body classes.

 *

 * @param array $classes Classes for the body element.

 * @return array

 */

    function voltov_body_classes( $classes ) {

        // Adds a class of group-blog to blogs with more than 1 published author.





             // Adds a class of group-blog to blogs with more than 1 published author.

        if ( is_multi_author() )

            $classes[] = 'group-blog';



        if(is_archive() || is_search())

            $classes[] =  'sidebar-disabled';



          return $classes;

      }

      add_filter( 'body_class', 'voltov_body_classes' );





    //add active class in selected page

    add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'voltov_nav_class' , 10 , 2);

    function voltov_nav_class($classes, $item){

         if( in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){

                 $classes[] = 'active ';  // your new class

         }

         return $classes;

    }





    /*

     Custom Excerpt

    */

    function voltov_get_excerpt($count,$read=true){

     global $post;

      $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);

      $excerpt = get_the_content();

      $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);

      $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, $count);

      $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));



      if($read != false){

             $excerpt = $excerpt.'<a class="readmore" href="'.$permalink.'"> '. __('Weiterlesen','voltov').'</a>';

      }

      echo wp_kses($excerpt,'a');

    }





    /*

    * Pagination code

    */

    function voltov_get_pagination($pages = '', $range = 4)



    { 

         $showitems = ($range * 2)+1; 

         global $paged;

         if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

         if($pages == '')

         {

             global $wp_query;

             $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

             if(!$pages)

             {

                 $pages = 1;

             }

         }  

         if(1 != $pages)

         {

             echo "<div class=\"pagination\">";

             if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo; First</a>";

              previous_posts_link('<i class="icon-chevron-left pagination-icon"></i>');

              //echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'><i class='icon-chevron-left pagination-icon'></i></a>";

             for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)

             {

                 if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))



                 {

                     echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class=\"current\">".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"inactive\">".$i."</a>";

                 }

             }

              //echo "<a href=\"".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."\"><i class='icon-chevron-right pagination-icon'></i></a>"; 

              next_posts_link('<i class="icon-chevron-right pagination-icon"></i>','');

             if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>Last &raquo;</a>";

             echo "</div>\n";

         }

    }





    /**

     * Thumbnail Resizer & Image functions

     *

     */



         function xv_get_resizer($image_url='',$width='',$height='',$crop='c'){



                $image ="http://placehold.it/{$width}x{$height}";





                if (!empty($image_url)) {        



                    $image = theme_thumb($image_url, $width, $height,$crop);

                }



                return esc_url($image);

        }



        function xv_get_thumbnail($width,$height){

            global $post;    



              $thumb ="http://placehold.it/{$width}x{$height}";

                 if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {        

                    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), "full");

                    $image_url = $image_src[0];

                    $thumb = theme_thumb($image_url, $width, $height, 'c');

                }



            return esc_url($thumb);

         }

        function xv_get_thumbnail_url($size = 'full'){

        global $post;    





             if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {        

                $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), $size);

                $image_url = $image_src[0];

            }else{

                $image_url = 'No Image';

            }



            return esc_url($image_url);

         }



        function xv_get_image_url($post_id){



                $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_id, "full");

                $image_url = $image_src[0];

                return esc_url($image_url);

         }



    /**

     * Checks if a post thumbnails is already defined.

     *

     */

    function voltov_is_post_thumbnail_set()

    {

        global $post;

        if (get_the_post_thumbnail()) {

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }

    }





    function voltov_autoset_featured_img()

    {

        global $post;



        $post_thumbnail = voltov_is_post_thumbnail_set();

        if ($post_thumbnail == true) {

            return get_the_post_thumbnail();

        }

        $image_args     = array(

            'post_type'      => 'attachment',

            'numberposts'    => 1,

            'post_mime_type' => 'image',

            'post_parent'    => $post->ID,

            'order'          => 'desc'

        );

        $attached_images = get_children($image_args, ARRAY_A);

        $first_image = reset($attached_images);

        if (!$first_image) {

            return false;

        }



        return get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $first_image['ID']);

    }  



      function xv_get_sidebars_array() {

        global $xv_data;



        $sidebars = array();

        $sidebars['default'] = __('Default', 'framework');

        if (isset($xv_data) && isset($xv_data['custom-sidebars']) && is_array($xv_data['custom-sidebars'])) {

          foreach ($xv_data['custom-sidebars'] as $sidebar) {

            $sidebars[sanitize_title ( $sidebar )] = $sidebar;

          }

        }

        return $sidebars;

      }

      function xv_page_sidebar_id($position, $default = 'default')

      {

        if (function_exists('get_field')) {

          $sidebar = get_field($position);

        } else {

          $sidebar = '';

        }

        if (empty($sidebar))

        {

          $sidebar = $default;

        }

        return $sidebar;

      }



      function xv_get_post_type_categories($post_type='')

      {

          if(!empty($post_type)){



              $terms = get_terms($post_type);



          }else{



              $args = array(

                'orderby' => 'name',

                'parent' => 0

                );

              $terms = get_categories( $args );



              }





              $categories = array();

              $categories[__('All', 'framework')] = '';

              foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                  $categories[] = $term->slug;

              }









              return $categories;



      }



      function xv_get_posts_list($post_type='')

      {

          global $post;





          $args       = array( 'numberposts' => -1,'post_type'=>$post_type);

          $posts      = get_posts($args);

          $posts_list = array();



          foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); 





                  $posts_list[] =  get_the_title( $post_id ) ;



                      // );





          endforeach;





              return $posts_list;



      }



    /**

     *  Include Menu Walker Class

     *

     */



      function xv_set_post_views($postID) {

          $count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count';

          $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);

          if($count==''){

              $count = 0;

              delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);

              add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');

          }else{

              $count++;

              update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);

          }

      }

      //To keep the count accurate, lets get rid of prefetching

      remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);





add_filter('mce_buttons','wysiwyg_editor');

function wysiwyg_editor($mce_buttons) {

    $pos = array_search('wp_more',$mce_buttons,true);

    if ($pos !== false) {

        $tmp_buttons = array_slice($mce_buttons, 0, $pos+1);

        $tmp_buttons[] = 'wp_page';

        $mce_buttons = array_merge($tmp_buttons, array_slice($mce_buttons, $pos+1));

    }

    return $mce_buttons;

}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT 2:**

Okay, I have tried simply to upload an other Logo for the header, it automaticaly creates a homelink to the site itself and disables access to change the link. So I guess its simply not possible for this theme.

Comment: can you use javascript?

Comment: yes, thats a great idea. Havent thought about it! I will try!

Comment: CSS is not a scripting language. You cannot (generally speaking) take action with it.

Comment: "I have a wordpress theme which does not grant access to templates..." Huh?

Comment: to .html files called it templates because the function says get_template_part

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: http://xvelopers.com/wp/themes/voltov3/ updated post

Comment: A theme can't deny you that access.

Comment: [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array of elements

Comment: It shouldnt but I was searching for about 1 hour, and didnt found a way to access html files.

Comment: You need to look up the  `grep` command or similar so you can quickly find the file behind any given markup.

Comment: If you have a local copy of the theme you can "search all files inside that folder" for "navbar-brand" with your editor and find that class in seconds. I use Komodo edit to do that and set the "scope" to the theme folder and action to "find all". That will find the class for you which will also reveal what file that code is on. http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/5.0/search.html#search_incr

Comment: Okay, I found it how they make it, they have an own package which they load and how they create the navbar. I have no clue how to change links there, my JS should work